# Error in line "return View(students.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC. What does this error mean?

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
'PagedList.PagedListExtensions.ToPagedList<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>
(System.Linq.IQueryable<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>, int, int)' and
'System.Web.Mvc.Pagination.ToPagedList<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>
(System.Linq.IQueryable<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>, int, int)'
```

Comment: well basically this means that you have two implementations of .ToPagedList that the system can use.  Since the system is not a mind reader, you need to specify which one to use, you can do this through a using statement.  If you're using this in a view it would be @using (namespace of preferred implementatation), in c# code just straight up using.

Answer (score 1):

Those methods have the same prototype, i.e. `.ToPagedList(System.Linq.IQueryable, int, int)` but they don't belong to the same package.

You have to precise which of the two methods you want to use, either by using the full name, i.e. `PagedList.PagedListExtensions.ToPagedList(System.Linq.IQueryable, int, int)` or `System.Web.Mvc.Pagination.ToPagedList(System.Linq.IQueryable, int, int)`; or by importing the correct package, i.e. `PagedList.PagedListExtensions` or `System.Web.Mvc.Pagination`

Comment: I have written using PagedList; but this did not resolve my error

Comment: Does your `students` variable comes from a class that implements multiple interfaces, both having a method called `ToPagedList(System.Linq.IQueryable, int, int)` ? That would explain the problem

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by first casting my data collection to IEnumerable, then calling the method of the PagedList class.

```
var csr = (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CaseSearchResult>)Model.CaseSearchResults;
var results = csr.ToPagedList<CaseSearchResult>(pageNum, pageSize);
```

I still don't get the second page of results when I click the pager, though, so I am not sure what is going on. I tried taking it out of the partial view and including it in the main form. Next I will try enclosing the search results in an Ajax form.